# What does ".csstransforms &" mean

Tags: css

I recently came across a css rule like this:

```
.csstransforms & th.rotate {
    ....
}
```

I am not able to figure out what `.csstransforms &` means and googling it didn't seem to find any relevant links.

Comment: Are you sure thats css and not Sass or Less?

Comment: @theoretisch No I am not sure, I was not even aware of Sass or Less, but it seems to be actually the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats just a class. 
You could also name it `.cssnewyearresolution` or `.cssforfun`.

I think that the `&` could be used from [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) or [Less](http://lesscss.org/).

[Referencing Parent Selectors: &](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector)

> Sometimes it’s useful to use a nested rule’s parent selector in other
>   ways than the default. For instance, you might want to have special
>   styles for when that selector is hovered over or for when the body
>   element has a certain class. In these cases, you can explicitly
>   specify where the parent selector should be inserted using the &
>   character.

Comment: `&` could be from Less too :)

Comment: @Harry Thanks. Added it.

Comment: `.csstransforms & th.rotate {` = `.csstransforms  th.rotate {` in css

Answer (score 2):

It's a little odd that there are few hits by Googling. **Modernizr.js** adds csstransforms and a chunk of other classes to your html element.